# Macro to copy and insert rows by variable number

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2003

I have an Excel 2003 worksheet with names and addresses, unique per row, to be used for shipping monthly magazines.

Some members receive more than one copy of the magazine, which will be indicated in one of the columns by a number (X). If X is higher than 1, I now have to manually copy that specific row X times and insert it into the worksheet.

Is there an easy way to automate this?

I'm thinking of letting a macro go through the column with numbers higher than 1 and automatically copy the rows X times. The order of the rows is not important, nor is the fact that it will obviously create duplicate rows.

Comment: For a start, I'd suggest using Excel's macro recorder to capture the steps you go through in doing the copy and paste. As you do that, think about the steps you would need to take if you were doing it blindfolded. After reviewing the macro's code, you will see how to get some things done, and you'll have more general questions of the that all macro beginners face - and you can then edit your question here so that you are more likely to get a useful answer to those questions.